# How to make just one text column be unquoted in final CSV?

Tags: export, csv, openoffice-calc, text-formatting

I'm using OO calc and i have one column with phone numbers that have leading 0s, which are vital for the number to be valid. I can format the cell as text but i do not want the numbers to be quoted when exported to csv. At the same time i have some other columns that need to stay automatically quoted . How can i do this?

Comment: Why don't you want the phone numbers to be quoted? So you can store them as numbers? As you found out yourself, that doesn't work. What about extensions? International numbers also have significant '+' symbols. They're text, store them as text.